# OSX 10.11 crashes after login progress bar

Tags: macos, startup, error

After I power on and type my password, there is a progress bar under my username. The progress moves from left to right and after finishing normally it would present my desktop. Now it goes to about 75% and then the system powers off completely.

I would like to know how I can recover from this.

I have tried to login to Disk Utility from the Recovery Mode.  I am able to see my disks and click First Aid > Run and it says the HDD is all good.

### Based on Comments

After doing `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` as suggested by @allan, it found pci pause SXDC.  Googleing, that I found [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/20exp7/bootup_stuck_on_pci_pause_sdxc/) which says

```
Boot in single user mode [and execute the following commands]
mount -uw /
mv /etc/launchd.conf /etc/launchd.conf.old
reboot
```

In my case I don't even see the `/etc/launchd.conf` file.

Comment: Type the following command: `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` and post the results.  You may also want to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: @Allan can you please let me know how to get the syslog? i am running the AHT test right now will post the results

Comment: Use Terminal.  Type that command exactly as you see it.  You can send the output directly to your clipboard for pasting into your original question by appending `| pbcopy` to the command.

Comment: it says pci pause sdxc updating questions with what i did with this message

Comment: Can you post the output to the question, please?

Comment: In recovery mode, did you check the physical disk (top entry) or the Macintosh HD volume (listed under the disk, indented)? You really need to check both. Note that in order to check the volume, you may need to unlock it (it sounds like you have FileVault encryption enabled).